# Habilitar CORS en una peticion FETCH despues de tenerla en el web.config

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cors

Tengo una aplicacion web .NET Framework que en el web.config tiene

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="connect-src 'self' https://*.googleapis.com https://*.facebook.com"/>
```

Ahora tengo que hacer un fetch a una URL y en el head del aspx le añado

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" value="connect-src 'self' https://site.del.cliente" />
```

Y no me funciona, entiendo que porque en el web.config no esta.
Exite alguna manera de forzar el cors a nivel individual dentro de la pagina nueva.

Gracias.

Necesitaría poder realizarlo en la pagina nueva para no sobrecargar el web.config, ya que la web la tengo en mas de 500 instalaciones.